# How to select top N record from every group MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where i want to get top N items from each group on the base of column `sub_category_id`. 
If i set `N=10` that would select first `10` rows from each group or if i set `N=5` then that would select top `5 rows from each group. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Yes my syntax is Mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.  Here is one using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where (select count(*)
       from t t2
       where t2.sub_category_id = t.sub_category_id and t2.id <= t.id
      ) <= 10;
```

Comment: `select sub_category_items.*
from sub_category_items
where (select count(*)
       from sub_category_items t2
       where t2.sub_category_id = sub_category_items.sub_category_id and t2.id <= sub_category_items.id
      ) <= 10`

Comment: This works, but I think the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30269273 with a join instead of a subquery probably performs better - I tried both variants, and they yield the same (correct) result, but the one with the join was faster than the one with the subquery.

Comment: @leo . . . That is actually irrelevant, because MySQL supports window functions now.

Comment: @GordonLinoff okay thanks but I'm stuck with an old version (5.x) of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `PARTITION BY` as below.

In my case, the table name was `company_perform_quter`. I used group by single column, order by multiple column and received latest four record.

```
SELECT* from (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY symbol, year DESC, month DESC, quater DESC) rowNum
FROM company_perform_quter) nn WHERE rowNum<=4
```